# Firefox position fixed element flash

Tags: html, css, firefox

This is only an issue in Firefox. I am using v60.0.2 (64-bit)

I am having an issue with a `position:fixed` div that is in a `transition` div. The `position:fixed` element will flicker in and out as the element transitions. It works as expected in Chrome, Edge, and IE. See codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZRoOxG

Edit:
Adding hardware acceleration works but I needed the `strange text` to stay in the same place when scrolling the slide out. I got it to work by not using the hardware acceleration and changing `position:fixed` to `position:sticky`. This does not work in chrome. I guess sticky is handled differently between browsers so I added

`@supports (-moz-appearance:none) {
   position: sticky;
}`

I hope this edit helps someone. I've spent too much time on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the element:

```
transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

to force the browser to use hardware acceleration. Basically you’re telling the browser you want to do a 3D transform, which forces it to access the GPU, making your transitions nice and crisp. You can learn more about hardware acceleration in CSS here:

https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-hardware-acceleration-css-animations/

Comment: Oh wow you are the best! thank you! `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` is the line I needed